# read file: pickup every text between the pattern including start and end pattern and create new file for each pattern set

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file called `file.txt` on Linux, containing:

```
sqlplus -s insert into table;  
commit;  
!  
sqlplus -s insert into table;  
commit;  
!  
sqlplus -s insert into table;  
commit;  
!
  
.  
.
```

I want to create multiple files as shown below:

File1.txt:-

```
sqlplus -s insert into table;  
commit;  
!
```

File2.txt

```
sqlplus -s insert into table;  
commit;  
!
```

Comment: So, how should the files be created? Why do your output examples have the same contents? Why only three lines? Please [edit] your question and _explain_ what you need, tell us what logic we should use to figure this out. Also, show us what you have done so far so we don't waste your time or ours giving you solutions you have already tried.

Comment: i have edited question hope my requirement is clear to you

Comment: Not really. You still haven't explained what you need. Don't just show the output, explain the logic of how we can get to the output from the input. Should we separate on every third line? Or should we look for the string `sqlplus` and then a line with just `!`? Or something else? We need to know how you want us to split.

Comment: your both logic will work   1. we can separate on every 3rd line or 2. get sqlplus ,,,,,, till "!"  i just want to create multiple files with above logic

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '/^sqlplus/ {close(sql);sql="file"++c".txt"} {print > sql}' input_file
$ head *
==> file1.txt <==
sqlplus -s insert into table;
commit;
!

==> file2.txt <==
sqlplus -s insert into table;
commit;
!

==> file3.txt <==
sqlplus -s insert into table;
commit;
!

.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical job for `awk`:

```
START_PATTERN='^sqlplus -s' END_PATTERN='^!$' awk '
  !file && $0 ~ ENVIRON["START_PATTERN"] {
    file = sprintf("file%03d.txt", ++n)
  }
  file {
    print > file
    if ($0 ~ ENVIRON["END_PATTERN"]) {
      file = ""
      close(file)
    }
  }' < your-file
```

That approach allows lines to match both start and end patterns (not possible in your case).

Answer (score 0):

If it is enough to make one file for every three lines of the original input file, you can do (with GNU `awk`):

```
awk 'NR%3==1{a++} {print > "file"a".txt"}' file.txt
```

Running this on your data produces:

```
$ ls file?.txt 
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt
```

Comment: @EdMorton fair enough, I limited it to GNU awk. As for the too many files, that can be a problem yes, but given the dearth of information in the OP, I am just going to assume it isn't. :P

Comment: As long as you say its gawk-only that;s fine as gawk can handle any number of open files.

Comment: Ah! So _that_ is why I've never seen this problem myself despite a couple of decades using awk! I only ever use `gawk`.

Comment: Right, gawk behaves as you'd want in many undefined behavior and other situations such as the 2 I mentioned and setting FS to null. If you were using the default awk on MacOS or busybox or any awk that comes with Solaris, etc. you'd have a very different experience :-).

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution with `csplit`

```
csplit infile -z -f 'file' '/^sqlplus/' '{*}'


╰─ → $ cat file00
sqlplus -s insert into table;
commit;
!
╰─ → $ cat file01
sqlplus -s insert into table;
commit;
!
╰─ → $ cat file02
sqlplus -s insert into table;
commit;
!
```

`-f` is used to set a prefix and `-z` to suppress empty files.